# How to boot if the graphics chip is damaged and the screen is permanently blank?

Tags: data-recovery, remote-control, remote-access

My ASUS Zenphone Selfie Pro 4 graphics chip burned and the screen is green at boot, becoming blank after a while.
Since I cannot see what is being 'shown' on the screen, how can I make the cellphone connect to wi-fi?
I guess the boot process is halted at the gesture request screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded to boot by guessing the moment to enter the security gesture.
Pressing the power button for 10s flashes green on the screen.
If the touch doesn't respond, pressing again for 10s flashes again, and the gesture must be done timely.